# function undefined - don't understand why

Tags: javascript

I have two functions with the same name, but i thought they were localized so i am not sure what I am not understanding here, it seems one of the functions isn't created or something.

I have my code setup like this - it starts from the bottom line:

```
function getDiv(id)    {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}


var account = new function(){

    this.load = function(){     
        //load user data from server to elements
    }


    this.init = function(){
        this.load(); //ERROR : this.load is not a function
    }
}

var template = new function(){    

    this.addEvents = function(){ 
         var el = getDiv('output');
         el.addEventListener('mousedown',account.init,false);

    }

    this.load = function(){ 
        //load template to page
        this.addEvents();
    }


    this.init = function(){
        this.load();
    }
}

template.init(); //start of the script: load template
```

I hope it makes reasonable sense in following where the code goes but i am not understanding why in `account.init` i get an error, but for `template.init` I do not - they are pretty similar setup.

What is causing this and how would i solve it ?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this in FF's scratchpad. Seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can’t reproduce. It works fine.

Comment: This works fine in the console in Chrome. Probably some other part of your code is broken.

Comment: Works fine on Chrome. (console).

Comment: oh hang on i know why - let me update question

Comment: I missed out the event listener which triggers `account.init`. see edit.

Comment: With your updated code, `getDiv` is undefined. Because it is, it's not included in the code.

Comment: console.log on `el` gives the element - its a function i have used many times it deffinately works as intended as the event listener also triggers correctly. But event listeners use `this` so its surely over riding the `this` in `account` right? At least thats why i think i am getting this error. As `this` would now be the element ?

Comment: Have added the getDiv function if it helps. :P

Comment: Yes, if you want `this` to refer to the `account` instance you'll need to save it as a closure `var self = this` and then use `self` inside your `account` functions.

Comment: @Jan but wouldn't `var self = this;` simply assign element to `self`?

Comment: What I don't really get is why you want to initiate the object on the click... Wouldn't you possibly at that point want to either use an already initialized account object OR create and add a new account to some sort of list on click?

Comment: @Jan i didn't think it would be creating another ? Thought it would be simply calling the function account.init and account is already set up with its functions.

Comment: @Dave yes, and `self` would be a closure for the methods inside `account` which they later can use to access their base object, instead of `this` being whatever scope it's executed in. And I meant already initialized account object. I'm trying to figure out what it really is you want to accomplish and if this is the best way. But the short term answer is, save a reference to `this` in a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the event listener `el.addEventListener('mousedown',account.init,false);`, the element `el` becomes the scope of `account.init` and that's where `this` will then refer to. To avoid it, save a reference to `this` as a closure.

```
var account = new function(){
    var self = this;
    this.load = function(){     
        //load user data from server to elements
    }
    this.init = function(){
        self.load(); // "this" as in "account" is accessible here through the closure "self"
    }
}
```

Info on `this` and closures https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2):

Event listeners aren't called with the same value for `this` as in the context they're added.

To set the value of `this` that's used, you can use the `bind` function:

```
el.addEventListener('mousedown', account.init.bind(account), false);
```

Comment: So `this` carries the element ? So how would i use that in `account` and also have `this` available to use ?

Comment: Instead of binding, use a closure.